# Determine the proximity distance of two string in python

Tags: python

Clean_data is list with over 9000 text files. rules is list of dictionary containing over 500 elements. Below is the rules list

```
rules = [{'id': 1, 'kwd_root': 'add', 'kwd_sub': 'price target', 'word_count': 5, 'occurance': 1, 'kwd_search': 1, 'status': 1}, {'id': 2, 'kwd_root': 'add', 'kwd_sub': 'PT', 'word_count': 5, 'occurance': 1, 'kwd_search': 1, 'status': 1},.....]
```

My Question is : I need apply the rules for each and every element in clean_data list.below is the code i have used

```
for word in clean_data:
    for i,d in enumerate(rules):
        if  any(d['kwd_root'] in word and d['kwd_sub'] in word):
            if abs(word.index(d['kwd_root']) - word.index(d['kwd_sub'])) <= d['word_count']:
            research.append(word)
        else:
            non_research.append(word)
    else:
            non_research.append(word)
```

After running this code i'm getting the len(non_research) to as 110000 and len(research) as 5500

But the expected output as len(non_research) + len(research) should be equal to len(clean_data)

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about the indentation of your posted code?

Comment: How can we know what is relation between clean_data and rules and what is in clean_data , int or str or what?

Answer (score 0):

The code indentation posted is wrong. On the other side, the line 3 you use 'any' which need a list as argument. In addition research/non_research append a value each word and each condition (word x condition times). Maybe you can use:

```
for word in clean_data:
    flag_rules = False
    for i,d in enumerate(rules):
        if d['kwd_root'] in word and d['kwd_sub'] in word:
            if abs(word.index(d['kwd_root']) - word.index(d['kwd_sub'])) <= d['word_count']:
                flag_rules = True
    if flag_rules:
        research.append(word) 
    else:
        non_research.append(word)
```

Comment: Carlos one quick question - what happens if kwd_sub is NULL does this will still work ??

Comment: @kabilan In python there isn't null like other languages but it use None so If you ask about None, it is a problem but you can check it before "d['kwd_sub'] not is None" in the same statement line. But when you said Null you mean that kwd_sub key doesn't exist in the dictionary so it's used method get() method in dictionary, this method allow to return defaul value.  
  Line 3:  
  `if any(d['kwd_root'] in word and d.get('kwd_sub', None) is not None and d['kwd_sub'] in word):`

Comment: if any(d['kwd_root'] in word and d.get('kwd_sub', None) is not None and d['kwd_sub'] in word):